# Computed property as in predicates, and as sortProperty in RealmSearchViewController?

Tags: swift, realm

I have a realm object `Song` with `dynamic var title = ""`. I've written a computed property, `sortedName` that sorts out any pesky prefixes like "The " or parentheses and punctuation. I want my `RealmSearchViewController` to use `sortedName` as its `sortProperty` but this is throwing the error: `"Property 'sortedName' not found in object of type 'Song'"`

I get the same error when using `sortedName` in predicates (such as `if results.objects(with: NSPredicate(format: "sortedName BEGINSWITH %@", key)).count > 0`)

I get this same behavior whether `sortedName` is written in my `Song` class or whether it's written in `extension Object` (which is what I want to do so I can use `sortedName` in my `Artist` and `Genre` classes as well).

The property does exist, and it works on its own: When I set    `cell.detailTextLabel?.text = song.sortedName` (after removing references that cause the above errors) it displays correctly.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Please post some actual code, including your Realm object definitions and the class where you are trying to access the sortedName property.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, at the moment, querying for Realm objects can only be done with non-computed, Realm-persisted properties.

There's plans within Realm to add [a feature where it's possible to manually sort Realm objects with a block](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/4318), but there's no time frame for that yet.

For the time being, you'd be better off copying the objects in `Results` to a Swift array and sort them in there. It's a bit of a performance hit (As it means having to access all of the Realm objects up front), but it will let you perform custom sorting on them.

Alternatively. You could 'cache' the sorted ordering by adding another type of Realm `Object` to your database that maintains a `List` object that controls the ordering of those objects.