# Realm IOS casting the Results of closure

Tags: swift, closures, realm

i have a realm Statement like

```
let foundFruits = try!  Realm().objects(fruits.self).filter("color = 'red'")
```

the result of this I use in an Tableview
.
.
.

```
let fruit = foundFruits[indexPath.row]
cell.color.text = fruit.color
```

.
.
.
now I make a second statement like

```
let foundFruits = try!  Realm().objects(fruits.self).filter({ $0.weight > o.7 $0.maxweight })
```

but because of the closure I get the error

> Cannot assign value of type
>   'LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection>' to type
>   'Results'

how can I cast the result of the second statement so that I can use it for my tableview??

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible. Realm doesn't provide functionality for custom filter blocks, hence if you want to keep the auto-updating `Results` type of your query, you need to use an `NSPredicate` for filtering the results. However, you can only use constants or keypaths for comparison in `NSPredicate`s, so `"weight > 0.7*maxWeight"` would result in an invalid predicate.

One feasible workaround could seem to be creating a computed property for your object class, whose value would be `0.7*maxWeight`, but Realm [doesn't support computed properties in queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834998/computed-property-as-in-predicates-and-as-sortproperty-in-realmsearchviewcontro) either.

The filtering you want to achieve is only possible using Swift's built in filter method, but as you can see, the return type of using a built in Swift filter won't be `Results`.

If you really need this predicate, at the moment, a feasible workaround is to store the results in a Swift array and update that array every time you need to use it. You can declare `foundFruits` to be a computed property of type `Array<Fruit>`, this way when you will be trying to access it, it will update automatically (even though the performance will probably be worse than for `Results`, since using this, you need to run the query every time you access `foundFruits).

This is, how you can achieve the workaround:

```
var foundFruits: Array<Fruit> {
    return Array(try! Realm().objects(Fruit.self).filter({Double($0.normalWeight) > 0.7*Double($0.maxWeight)}))
}

print(foundFruits)
```

Also make sure that you conform to the Swift naming convention, which is Upper-camelCase for class names. For the sake of this, I have renamed your `fruits` class to `Fruit`, keep this in mind when using this piece of code in your project.